# Permutations of several lists in python efficiently

Tags: python, random, permutation, product, python-itertools

I'm trying to write a python script that will generate random permutations of several lists without repeating

```
i.e. [a,b] [c,d]
a, c
b,c,
a,d
b,d
```

I can generate every permutation using the following, however the result is somewhat non random:

```
for r in itertools.product(list1, list2):
        target.write("%s,%s" % (r[0], r[1])
```

Does anyone know a way i can implement this such that I can extract only 2 permutations, and they will be completely random but ensure that they will never be repeated?

Comment: How many elements are in the list?

Comment: the purpose i am using it for will actually have 5 lists, each with 100 odd members thus the need to efficiently extract random non repeated samples

Answer (score 2):

You can use `random.choice()`:

```
>>> from itertools import product
>>> import random
>>> l1 = ['a', 'b', 'c']
>>> l2 = ['d', 'e', 'f']
>>> prod = tuple(product(l1, l2))
>>> 
>>> random.choice(prod)
('c', 'e')
>>> random.choice(prod)
('a', 'f')
>>> random.choice(prod)
('c', 'd')
```

Or simply use a nested list comprehension for creating the products:

```
>>> lst = [(i, j) for j in l2 for i in l1]
```

If you don't want to produce duplicate items you can use a set object which will create a set object from your product without an specified order then you can simply pot the items from it:

```
>>> prod = set(product(l1, l2))
>>> 
>>> prod.pop()
('c', 'f')
>>> prod.pop()
('a', 'f')
>>> prod.pop()
('a', 'd')
```

Or use shuffle in order to shuffle the iterable, as @ayhan has suggested in his answer.

Comment: `itertools.product` seems to be slightly faster than the list comprehension.

Comment: @ByteCommander No it's not faster it's just more optimized in terms of memory usage, because it returns a generator.

Comment: Hi Kasramvd. Thanks for the response!. With regards to your first suggestion, what is product() defined as?. Correct me if I'm wrong, but this does not ensure that a particular combination of the two lists is not presented twice does it?. Obviously this is unlikely for large lists, but I'm looking for an efficient way to generate randomised permutations without the risk of duplication (purely an exercise of learning / interest - I'm, not sure of a real use case for this)

Comment: Hi Kasramvd, Thanks for the response. Just so I understand your answer better, can you explain what product() is defined as. I'm getting a 'Product' is not defined error in Python 2.7. Is this an imported lib / custom function?

Comment: @user3484575 It's the `product` function from `itertools` module. I forgot to add the import line. Check out the edit for fixed version.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `random.shuffle` then `pop` to make sure the results will not be repeated:

```
list1 = ["a", "b"]
list2 = ["c", "d"]
p = list(itertools.product(list1, list2))
random.shuffle(p)
e1 = p.pop()
e2 = p.pop()
```

`list(itertools.product())` is not efficient as it generates and stores all of them. If you have big lists you can generate one at a time and check whether they are duplicated:

```
s = set()
list1 = ["a", "b"]
list2 = ["c", "d"]
while True:
    r = (random.choice(list1), random.choice(list2))
    if r not in s:
        target.write("%s,%s" % (r[0], r[1]))
        s.add(r)
        break
```

Comment: Shuffling the entire list instead of picking a single random element is faster as soon as you need at least about 4 or more random elements. For fewer results, picking single items as described in Kasramvd's answer is slightly faster. - And your second option is a very nice approach to save memory! Great.

Comment: @ByteCommander I agree but those `random.choice` calls are independent so they can produce the same result (in fact they produce the same result just in the second call in Kasramvd's answer).